# Cannot focus/type in EditText field in TableRow

Tags: java, android

My Android application so far has been going well apart from I'm using the TableLayout in order to structure some data. However, when I add a EditText object in the row, I can no longer type in it.

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Does the title match?" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checktextview_doestitlematch_confirm_item_specs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="false"
                android:duplicateParentState="true"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:onClick="toggleTitle" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="Name" />


        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </TableLayout>
```

I've looked and people mainly have this issue with ListViews. I've tried following some suggestions but hit a brick wall. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove from the Table layout the attribute android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants". With that attribute the children can't be focusable

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems I've just seen this as a fix for another issue and put it on. Marked as solved answer.